# Help with deciphering shorthand C

Tags: c, embedded

I'm trying to figure out some things with some firmware that was written for us. I'm not all that familiar with C and I think there's some shorthand going on here that I'm just not getting.  I don't understand how the code relates to the comments, particularly how you get 70ms from any of that.  Can you help translate into English?

```
// so the button has to be held for 70 ms to be considered being pressed
// and then has to be released for 70ms to be considered un-pressed
State=(State<<1) | !input(USER_BUTTON) | 0xe000;
if(State==0xe000)
{
    Debounced_Button_Pressed =  TRUE;
    time_button_held++;
}
else if (State==0xffff)
{
    Debounced_Button_Pressed =  FALSE;
}
```

This is within a timer interrupt function and apparently fires every 4.4ms

Thanks.

Comment: there isn't really enough info without knowing what State originally was and what 0xE000 represents (which is probably just a register bitfield)

Comment: this code was copied from http://www.ganssle.com/debouncing.pdf page 20

Comment: @Mark - I knew it looked familiar

Comment: Ahhha!  You know, I was wondering why he used State as a variable... it is not consistent with the rest of the styling (nothing else is capitalized) and we already had a variable "state".  Not that it mattered, but this explains it.  On the one hand, I'm glad he didn't reinvent the wheel... on the other, do we now have a copyright issue or is this all kosher?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's take this one step at a time...

```
State=(State<<1) | !input(USER_BUTTON) | 0xe000;
```

What this does is:

- Shift state one to the left (throw out the top bit, move everything over, set the low bit to 0)
- Set the low bit if the input is 0 (off)
- Force the top 3 bits on.

So, there are 13 bits here that are not forced on, and they form a sort of history of the last 13 samples of the USER_BUTTON input.

The if statement then just checks whether all 13 of those bits are off (giving 0xe000) or on (giving 0xffff). If off, the button's been *pressed* for 13 samples; if on, it's been *un-pressed* for 13 samples.

This then gives a debounce time of 4.4ms * 13 = 57.2ms - a bit off from the comment, or the timer interval's closer to 5.385ms.

Comment: Thank you! This is most helpful in figuring it out.  Any chance you can take me through a few iterations asssuming State starts at zero and input(USER_BUTTON) is false (for example) doesn't it just get infinitely larger?   | means a bitwise OR, right?  So when I get out my handy windows programming calculator the results for the first 3 are:

E001
1E003
3E007

and we can already see there's no hope of it being 0xffff or 0xe000 ever again.  What simple obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: State is likely an unsigned short, meaning it's truncated at 16 bits (4 hex digits) each time.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the varialbe "State" as 16 bits.  The << operator shifts it left by one each time, and the | operator is used to set the least significant bit whenever input(USER_BUTTON) is false (! is the not operator).  The checks then just check if the last 13 cases of input were all true or all false.

Answer (score 2):

He's debouncing a switch by shifting samples of the switch's state into an integer every 4.4ms.  He can then tell a valid press from noise by seeing if the contents of that integer match a certain hex value.  It looks like he can also tell if it has been released according to his definition by comparing it to a different value.